# Oracle update statement on overly indexed table

Tags: c#, oracle

I am struggling with a simple update statement in Oracle. The update itself has not changed in forever but the table has grown massively and the performance is now unacceptable.
Here is the low down:
70 columns
27 indexes (which I am not under any circumstances allowed to reduce)
50M rows
Update statement is just hitting one table.

Update statement:

```
update TABLE_NAME 
  set NAME = 'User input string', 
  NO = NO, 
  PLANNED_START_DATE = TO_DATE('3/2/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'), 
  PLANNED_END_DATE = TO_DATE('3/2/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'), 
  WHERE ID = 999999 /*pk on the table*/
```

Execution Plan:

```
    ==================
      Plan hash value: 2165476569

  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT             |                |     1 |   245 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE                      | TABLE_NAME     |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_NAME     |     1 |   245 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_INDEX       |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

       3 - access("ID"=35133238)

==================================================
```

The update statement originates in a C# application but I am free to change the statement there. 
 Select statements still perform well thanks to all the indexes but as I see it that is exactly what is wrong with the update - it has to go update all the indexes.
We are licensed for partitioning but this table is NOT partitioned.

How can I improve the performance of this update statement without altering the table or its indexes?

Comment: Is the ID column the only column in the primary key? If so, is the PK_INDEX indexed only on the ID column, or does it also have other columns in it? I'm surprised by the cardinality of 188 when selecting a single value from the supposed primary key. Also, how many indexes are the columns you're updating in?

Comment: Also, are your stats up to date on the table and its indexes?

Comment: Thanks for the spot - I had included the Explain Plan from a different system. I have edited above to include correct explain plan output now. @Aleksey this is also why the 188 rows were showing (its not a unique value in the dev system)

Comment: Also, stats are updated nightly

Comment: And how many indexes are your  NAME, NO, PLANNED_START_DATE and PLANNED_END_DATE columns in? Also, why are you setting NO = NO? There's not much point in updating a column to be the exact same value! Unnecessary and extra work - you should remove that. Another thought: are there any triggers on this table?

Comment: NAME and NO are not in indexes. PLANNED_START_DATE and PLANNED_END_DATE are both in one index each. The NO = NO is pointless but comes from the way the C# application is written. Any of those fields in the object could be updated so it saves them all back once the user submitted. If refactoring the code is the only way to improve performance, we can go there but with 50M rows in the table we were hoping there was something we could do to streamline the Oracle side of things first.

Comment: I wouldn't expect an update of a single row based on the primary key that affects a couple of other indexes to take long at all. How long is it taking for you?

Comment: Its taking about 45 seconds which isn't terribly slow but in the context of the application it is. Users are at best giving out and at worst timing out

Comment: That's... not good. Have you tried running SQL monitoring for the query to see where the time is being spent?

Comment: I don't really have tools to do SQL monitoring (unless I can do it through SQL developer??) I will put a request into our DBA's and see if they'll monitor it in Enterprise manager

Comment: Real time SQL monitoring can be called direct from the stored proc, but it looks like SQL developer has support for it: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/10/real-time-sql-monitoring-support-in-oracle-sql-developer-video/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that column id is primary key? And is primary key based on unique index? Because in this case CBO would use INDEX UNIQUE SCAN. In your plan CBO expected 188 rows using filter ID (primary kay) = value and uses INDEX RANGE SCAN